# Confused by what it means for a gradle task to "execute"

Tags: gradle

It was my understanding that printlns get displayed during a task's configuration phase (unless they are for example placed within a doLast action). Therefore given the following task:

```
ext {
    changeset       = 'placeholderChangeset'
}

task getChangeset {
    process = '/usr/bin/git describe --always'.execute()
    process.waitFor()
    changeset = process.getText()
    println "Changeset obtained from GIT is: $changeset"

    doLast {
        println '\n++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
        println '+++++ task getChangeset executed'
        println '++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++'
    }
}
```

If I run this using `./gradlew` then the output will be:

```
********************************
** task getChangeset
********************************
Changeset obtained from GIT is: 9bd49ca
```

If it run it using `./gradlew getChangeset` then the output will be:

```
********************************
** task getChangeset
********************************
Changeset obtained from GIT is: 9bd49ca

...
:app:getChangeset
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++ task getChangeset executed
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

In the first run, the task has not been executed. Yet the value of the changeset is displayed, and therefore the process = ... execute() line has been executed.

Therefore I'm confused, what does it actually mean for a task to be "executed", if in this example, it obviously doesn't mean the code statements within the task haven't executed, as they most clearly have in order to get the value of the changeset. 
What's the difference between a task not executing and a task executing if its not having an effect on the execution or non execution of the code within the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `println` isn't somehow special or different from other code. Any code that is not inside the `doLast{}` block will be executed in the configuration phase, and the `dolast{}` block will be executed in the execution phase.